# C++ Compare Function Weird Behavior Inside A Class

Tags: c++, c++11, g++, clang++

I am a newbie in C++. I have tried my best to make the title more meaningful. I am trying to solve a K-NN problem (in 2D). I find this block of code works (Maybe you can skip it and look at the problem first):

```
// Example program
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <queue>
#include <math.h>  
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

struct Point { 
    double x;
    double y; 
    Point(double a, double b) {
        x = a;
        y = b;
    }
};

double getDistance(Point a, Point b) {
    return sqrt((a.x - b.x) * (a.x - b.x) + (a.y - b.y) * (a.y - b.y));
}
typedef bool (*comp)(Point, Point);
Point global_origin = Point(0,0);
bool compare(Point a, Point b)
{
   return (getDistance(a, global_origin)< getDistance(b, global_origin));
}

vector<Point> Solution(vector<Point> &array, Point origin, int k) {
    global_origin = Point(origin.x, origin.y);
    priority_queue<Point, std::vector<Point>, comp> pq(compare);
    vector<Point> ret;
    for (int i = 0; i < array.size(); i++) {
        Point p = array[i];
        pq.push(p);
        if (pq.size() > k)
            pq.pop();
    }
    int index = 0;
    while (!pq.empty()){
        Point p = pq.top();
        ret.push_back(p);
        pq.pop();
    }
    return ret;
}

int main()
{
   Point p1 = Point(4.5, 6.0);
   Point p2 = Point(4.0, 7.0);
   Point p3 = Point(4.0, 4.0);
   Point p4 = Point(2.0, 5.0);
   Point p5 = Point(1.0, 1.0);
   vector<Point> array = {p1, p2, p3, p4, p5};
   int k = 2;
   Point origin = Point(0.0, 0.0);
   vector<Point> ans = Solution(array, origin, k);
   for (int i = 0; i < ans.size(); i++) {
       cout << i << ": " << ans[i].x << "," << ans[i].y << endl;
   }
}
```

However, if I want to put the solution part into a class like this:

```
// Example program
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <queue>
#include <math.h>  
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

struct Point { 
    double x;
    double y; 
    Point(double a, double b) {
        x = a;
        y = b;
    }
};
class MySolution {
public:
  double getDistance(Point a, Point b) {
      return sqrt((a.x - b.x) * (a.x - b.x) + (a.y - b.y) * (a.y - b.y));
  }
  typedef bool (*comp)(Point, Point);
  Point global_origin = Point(0,0);
  bool compare(Point a, Point b)
  {
     return (getDistance(a, global_origin)< getDistance(b, global_origin));
  } 

  vector<Point> Solution(vector<Point> &array, Point origin, int k) {
      global_origin = Point(origin.x, origin.y);
      priority_queue<Point, std::vector<Point>, comp> pq(compare);
      vector<Point> ret;
      for (int i = 0; i < array.size(); i++) {
          Point p = array[i];
          pq.push(p);
          if (pq.size() > k)
              pq.pop();
      }
      int index = 0;
      while (!pq.empty()){
          Point p = pq.top();
          ret.push_back(p);
          pq.pop();
      }
      return ret;
  }
};


int main()
{
   Point p1 = Point(4.5, 6.0);
   Point p2 = Point(4.0, 7.0);
   Point p3 = Point(4.0, 4.0);
   Point p4 = Point(2.0, 5.0);
   Point p5 = Point(1.0, 1.0);
   vector<Point> array = {p1, p2, p3, p4, p5};
   int k = 2;
   Point origin = Point(0.0, 0.0);
   vector<Point> ans = MySolution().Solution(array, origin, k);
   for (int i = 0; i < ans.size(); i++) {
       cout << i << ": " << ans[i].x << "," << ans[i].y << endl;
   }
}
```

I compiled it with g++, and get

```
kcloset_copy.cpp:32:58: error: reference to non-static member function must be called
      priority_queue<Point, std::vector<Point>, comp> pq(compare);
                                                         ^~~~~~~
1 error generated.
```

I tried several different ways of writing the compare function. Every method works outside a class fails when I wrap it in a class. I am intersted in the reason and also, how to do it if I want to make in a class.

Thanks for the replying. I tried all the codes provided below and none of them work. Some answers even proposed two solutions, and none of them work, either. Like the overloading method, it gives

```
"/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/__functional_base:61:21: error: 
      invalid operands to binary expression ('const Point' and 'const Point')
        {return __x < __y;}
                ~~~ ^ ~~~
"
```

. I will be grateful if someone can give me any code that actually works.

Comment: Please add your solution as an answer instead you can also accept your own answer after a few days, see [tour] to learn more

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved by my friend. Just put the solution here for anyone who may encounter the same problem, note that global_origin is outside the class(or you can declare it to be a static member and declare it again outside the class. You can also build the operator in a nested structure/class inside MySolution class, and pass the nested structure/class as the third argument of priority_queue):

```
Point global_origin;    
class MySolution {
public:
  double getDistance(Point a, Point b) {
      return sqrt((a.x - b.x) * (a.x - b.x) + (a.y - b.y) * (a.y - b.y));
  }
  bool operator()(Point a, Point b)
  {
     return (getDistance(a, global_origin)< getDistance(b, global_origin));
  } 

  vector<Point> Solution(vector<Point> &array, Point origin, int k) {
      global_origin = Point(origin.x, origin.y);
      priority_queue<Point, std::vector<Point>, MySolution> pq;
      vector<Point> ret;
      for (int i = 0; i < array.size(); i++) {
          Point p = array[i];
          pq.push(p);
          if (pq.size() > k)
              pq.pop();
      }
      int index = 0;
      while (!pq.empty()){
          Point p = pq.top();
          ret.push_back(p);
          pq.pop();
      }
      return ret;
  }
};
```

Answer (score -1):

Please repeat after me a couple of times: A non-member function is *not* the same as a non-static member function. A non-static member function needs an *object* to be called on (that becomes the `this` pointer inside the funciton), a non-member function needs no such thing.

The simplest solution to your problem is not to create an explicit comparison function, but to overload the `operator<` function for the `Point` type, and let the queue use the standard comparison.

That is:

```
bool operator<(Point const& p1, Point const& p2);
```

and then just

```
std::priority_queue<Point> pq;
```

Answer (score -1):

If you implement operator < for your type you can then rely on std::less and the default template argument to prioity_queue will work:

```
bool operator<(Point const & a, Point const & b)
{
   return (getDistance(a, global_origin)< getDistance(b, global_origin));
}
...
std::priority_queue<Point> q;
```

If you insist on implementing it as a separate functor you need to implement operator() on that type:

```
struct MyPointCompare {
 bool operator()(Point const & a, Point const & b)
  {
    return (getDistance(a, global_origin)< getDistance(b, global_origin));
  }
};
```

Comment: The second method gives "error: use of non-static data member 'global_origin' of 'MySolution'
      from nested type 'MyPointCompare'"

Answer (score -1):

Because "compare" in the second case is a method and not a function object. Method is not same as function. 
Method are associated with class instances (objects) and don't exist independently.
Reference to a non-static method can only exist after the object of a class is created and cannot be referenced within the class. In this case, since compare method is not static, the reference to that method is not valid.

For eg: U can try by defining compare member as static bool compare(..)